# Recover data from unallocated partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

I've got a problem with my external hard drive (500Go).
I wanted to create a system repair disc on a separate partition (10 Go) with the official tool from Microsoft. (this partition was the first in the hard drive)

But the tool has extended the partition (to 32 Go) and the second has been truncated and became unallocated.
I have a lot of things on it, and after some days I desperate to find a (free) way to recover all my data. 
Some tools ask to paid after check all my hard drive, (lost 2 hours each times ...), some doens't work with unallocated partition...

I think partition's index is lost but most of data are still here because the tools i tried find files.

Did someone know a free tool to do that ? Or is it possible to do this with Windows disc tool ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use the tool [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) to try recovering your lost partition and its data in.

**Important**: first off, don't **write** any data on that external HDD before to run the app.

Tutorials:

- [TestDisk 7.2 WIP- Running Disk Recovery on Win10 Laptop (6th Feb 2020)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJrFbsdjcCc)
- [how to use testdisk to recover deleted files || testdisk tutorial in windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYa1E30qjJs)
- [How to Recover Lost Data and Partitions using TestDisk](http://How%20to%20Recover%20Lost%20Data%20and%20Partitions%20using%20TestDisk)

Comment: When testdisk fails (which I suspect it will), you may be able to - with difficulty - use its partner tool photorec to try recover remnants of files off the drive.